# Remove characters in array from file CSV PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Hey guys I'm geting a file CSV and when use print I have the output

```
 $excelImoveis = $request->file('excel_imoveis');
 $filePath = $excelImoveis->getRealPath();
 $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
 $header = fgetcsv($file);

 $array = [];   

 dd($header);

 while (($columns = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ';')) !== FALSE) { 
      dd($header);
        $array[] = array_combine(array_filter($header), array_filter($columns));
 }
```

Outupu

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => b"Código do Imóvel;FotoImovel;destaque;ordem"
]
```

How to remove "b" this item ?
maybe this implied the error of array_conbine():

```
$array[] = array_combine(array_filter($header), array_filter($columns));
```

Error: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Answer (score 1):

Change the line that reads the file header to use the correct seperator

```
$header = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ';');
```

Comment: I've done this, but the same thinks  0 => b"Código do Imóvel"
  1 => "FotoImovel"
  2 => "destaque"
  3 => "ordem"

Answer (score 1):

`array_filter` removes empty-evaluated values (such as `0`, `"0"`, `""`, `null`, `false`). So if one of your column has empty value, the number of elements will be different with header's and `array_combine` will fail.

Comment: As they are reading the header separated by `,` (the default) the header shown in the question shows it is all one field.  So the data is unlikely to match the header in the `array_combine()`

Comment: @NigelRen I see OP's code already use `;` as separator but maybe he forgot to update the "output" section. If both header and rows use same separator, all lines will be read as one field and `array_combine` would not fail

Comment: `$header = fgetcsv($file);`?

Comment: the problem is that "b" appears in some lines : 0 => b"Código do Imóvel;FotoImovel;destaque;ordem"

Comment: I've tried fgetcsv($file) and fgetcsv($file, 1000, ';'); too